# Cannot sign-out O365 after "Keep me signed in"

Tags: office-365, forms-authentication, internet-explorer

Maybe not really SharePoint question, but maybe someone faced this...
Signed in to SharePoint Online from O365 with MS account (X-Forms Authentication) with flag "Keep me signed out" from native C++ application (Internet Explorer WinInet).
Now any request to the SharePoint is performed without ask for authentication. Nothing helped:

1. sending GET to https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf
2. sending GET to https://login.live.com/logout.srf
3. clearing WinInet cookies with `InternetSetOptionW(nullptr,
   INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, nullptr, 0)`
4. searching for stored credentials in Credential Manager

Does any one know what request to send for signing out?

Comment: Dear @andrii Are you checked this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507767

Comment: I am wondering if the cookies got cleared successfully.

Comment: @Mp Arvind Well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375540/how-to-clear-cookie-through-wininet-function and it works for "forgetting" Dropbox auth tokens

Answer (score 0):

- Method 1: Add sites to the "Local intranet" and "Trusted sites" zones in the n the web browser.
- Method 2: Close and reopen all web browsers.
- Method 3: Sign out of all Microsoft online services.
- Method 4: Clear cookies from the web browser.

For more details, you should check [Problems when signing out of Office 365 in a web browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507767) , [Sign out of your Microsoft account](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sign-out-of-your-Microsoft-account-268b49c8-398f-4057-8a3f-e376789f273a)

Comment: I believe @andrii wants to achieve it through code!

Comment: @Mp Arvind yes, indeed! I have shown web browser to user for signing in from my application and need the way for him to sign out from the same application.

Comment: @Mr.Qassas Method 4 and Method 5 don't work for me (though I cannot close all browsers programmatically, I did it with IE API - this way does clear IE cookies and it works for e.g. Dropbox). The problem described on the referred page is when user gets error on sign out. My case is when user signs out on web page but IE API is still able to create connection with SharePoint Online without any authentication. This looks like some data is stored on the service... but how to reset it?